# don't find class in root directory in use of spl_autoload_register

Tags: php, autoload, spl-autoload-register

I use of spl_autoload_register for class auto loading like bellow

```
spl_autoload_register(array($this, 'mainLoader'));

function mainLoader($class) {
    $dirs = explode(CLASS_SEPARATOR, $class);
    $dirsLen = count($dirs);
    $class_name = $dirs[$dirsLen - 1];
    if ($dirsLen > 1) {
      $paths = array_slice($dirs, 0, $dirsLen - 1);
      $path = ROOT . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . implode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $paths) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
      set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $path);
    } else {
      set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . ROOT);
    }
    spl_autoload_extensions(".php");
    spl_autoload($class_name);
  }
```

input class name can be class, dir_class, dir_dir_class, ...
and file can be ROOT/class.php Root/dir/class.php , Root/dir/dir/class.php, ...
but when I run program Error to me

```
Fatal error:  Class 'class' not found in ...
```

why my auto loader don't work correctly??

note: this function work good in Windows but don't work in Linux Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0):

You're probably using camelCase names to your files. 
Unix is case sensitive in file names and spl_autoload will work just with lower case.